# Как сделать автозаполнение формы?

Tags: php, javascript

А как так сделать, чтоб я смог на сайте нажать на продукт и я перелетал на страницу с заказом, где в форме "ваш заказ" было уже это написано?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение абсолютно нетривиально. Во-первых, эти данные нужно где-то заполнить ранее. Например, в профиле пользователя, далее эти данные должны подтягиваться в форму заказа. Можно из БД, можно из куки.

Answer (score 2):

Если данные о продукте в виде ссылки (например, картинка + название), то параметры можно передавать get-запросом. Например,

```
<a href="cart.php?id=3&n=4">...</a>
```

Если надо передать некоторую инфу, вводимую пользователем (кол-во товара или что-то подобное), то нужно воспользоваться формой.

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="n" value="0" />
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение достаточно тривиально. Для каждого товара генерируем свою ссылку на страницу с формой заказа, в которой одним из параметров передаем код товара (например: `http://yoursite.com/order.php?productId=5131` - ссылка для товара с кодом 5131). При генерации формы заказа, учитываем этот параметр.

Это, разумеется, для случая с одним товаром. Если товаров в корзину добавляется несколько, то, действительно, нужно где-то накапливать эти данные(например в базе данных).

Answer (score 1):

Универсальнее всего на мой взгляд все-таки сессия. Это решение подойдет для любого числа товаров, да и вообще информации о тех или иных действиях пользователя. 
Если просто прокидывать ID товара через URL, то при следующем заходе в "корзину" (ну или как там называется оформление заказа) - этого ID уже не увидеть. Можно прокидывать через URL, но писать в сессию, можно сделать кнопку "добавить в корзину" и писать в сессию аяксом.. да мало ли способов - главное, что эта инфа уже не потеряется